# Copy reqwest bytes_stream in to tokio file

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, reqwest

I'm attempting to copy a file downloaded with reqwest in to a tokio file. This file is too large to store in memory so it needs to be through the [`bytes_stream()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.12/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.bytes_stream) rather than [`bytes()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.12/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.bytes)

I had attempted the following

```
let mut tmp_file = tokio::fs::File::from(tempfile::tempfile()?);
let byte_stream = reqwest::get(&link).await?.bytes_stream();
tokio::io::copy(&mut byte_stream, &mut tmp_file).await?;
```

This fails due to

```
    |
153 |     tokio::io::copy(&mut byte_stream, &mut tmp_file).await?;
    |     --------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `tokio::io::AsyncRead` is not implemented for `impl Stream<Item = Result<bytes::bytes::Bytes, reqwest::Error>>`
    |     |
    |     required by a bound introduced by this call
```

Is there any way I can get the trait AsyncRead on the Stream or otherwise copy this data in to the file? The reason I'm using a tokio file is I later need to AsyncRead from it. Perhaps it would make sense to copy in to a regular std::File and then convert it to a tokio::fs::File?

Comment: I thing you have to call [`StreamExt::for_each`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.25/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.for_each) on your stream and for each packet write it to the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This method works. Loosely based on the example for [`bytes_stream()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.12/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.bytes_stream)

Note: You probably want to [buffer the writes here](https://nnethercote.github.io/perf-book/io.html#buffering)

```
use futures::StreamExt;

let mut tmp_file = tokio::fs::File::from(tempfile::tempfile()?);
let mut byte_stream = reqwest::get(&link).await?.bytes_stream();

while let Some(item) = byte_stream.next().await {
  tokio::io::copy(&mut item?.as_ref(), &mut tmp_file).await?;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me idk why bytes_stream() is not working. It says method doesn't exist. So I found some other way to do it maybe that helps.

```
//Creating a client and hitting get req
let client = Client::new();
let mut response = client.get(url).send().await?;

//Creating file in using tokio to get async functionality
let mut file = tokio::fs::File::create(file_name).await?;
while let Some(chunk) = response.chunk().await? {
    file.write_all(&chunk).await?;
}
```

Comment: *"idk why bytes_stream() is not working"* - could be that you didn't enable the `"stream"` feature.